# How do i go through a binary heap in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

```
.data

decoder_heap: .asciiz "_ETIANMSURWDKGOHVF*L*PJBXCYZQ**54*3***2&*+****16=/***(*7***8*90"
str_eingabe: .asciiz "morse_in:"
str_ausgabe: .asciiz "\ntext_out: "
str_rueckgabewert: .asciiz "\nRueckgabewert: "
buf_out: .space 256

.text

.eqv SYS_PUTSTR 4
.eqv SYS_PUTCHAR 11
.eqv SYS_PUTINT 1
.eqv SYS_EXIT 10

main:
    
    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_eingabe
    syscall

    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, test_msg
    syscall
    
    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_rueckgabewert
    syscall

    move $v0, $zero


    la $a0, decoder_heap
    la $a1, test_msg
    la $a2, buf_out
    jal morse
    
    
    move $a0, $v0
    li $v0, SYS_PUTINT
    syscall
    
    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_ausgabe
    syscall
    
    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, buf_out
    syscall

    
    li $v0, SYS_EXIT
    syscall

.data

test_msg: .asciiz ".... .- .-.. .-.. ---"

.text

morse:

    lb $t0, 0($a1)
    
    beq $t0, '\0', exit

decoderLoop:

    lb $t0, 0($a1)
    
    beq $t0, ' ', positionInHeap
    beq $t0, '\0', positionInHeap
    
    #
    
    beq $t0, '.', isDot
    beq $t0, '-', isDash
    
    j exit
    
isDot:

    #
    
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    j decoderLoop

isDash:

    #
    
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    j decoderLoop


positionInHeap: blt $a0, 63, positionInHeap

    lb $t1, 0($a0)
    sb $t1, 0($a2)
    
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    addi $a2, $a2, 1
    addi $v0, $v0, 1
    
    j morse

exit:
    
    jr $ra
```

So this is a home assignment, and I've come this far, but I am really struggling at one point. I've written this code in MIPS-Assembler and assembler is still pretty new to me. I've understood the basics of this language, but I've still got plenty to learn.

This code decodes a morse code into an ASCIIZ string output. We are not allowed to modify the code above the label "morse" (only "test_msg"), and we also have to use exactly those registers. So, I think my code could work if I could correctly locate the index in the "decoder_heap" for every dot and dash. The "decoder_heap" is a binary heap, and to select the left child of the current node, if a dot was read, one has to set k = 2*k + 1. The same is true for the right node; if a dash was read, set k = 2*k + 2, where k is the current index. I am completely confused with this k.

My first attempt was to add $a0 and $a0 in $a0 and add 1 for a dot and 2 for a dash. But I got an arithmetic overflow. I would really appreciate your help on this one. Many thanks in advance for considering my request.

I also thought to store $a0 + $a0 in a register, like $t2, but this still didn't work.

So this is the revised version:

```
morse:

    lb $t0, 0($a1)
    
    beq $t0, '\0', exit
    
    li $t2, 0
    
decoderLoop:

    lb $t0, 0($a1)
    
    beq $t0, ' ', positionInHeap
    beq $t0, '\0', positionInHeap
    
    add $t2, $t2, $t2
    
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    
    beq $t0, '.', isDot
    beq $t0, '-', isDash
    
    j exit
    
isDot:
    
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    j decoderLoop

isDash:

    add $t2, $t2, 1
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    j decoderLoop


positionInHeap:
    
    add $a0, $a0, $t2

    lb $t1, 0($a0)
    sb $t1, 0($a2)
    
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    addi $a2, $a2, 1
    addi $v0, $v0, 1
    
    j morse

exit:
    
    jr $ra
```

Comment: _"My first attempt was to add $a0 and $a0 in $a0 and add 1 for a dot and 2 for a dash."_ that sounds correct. Show your code. Also don't forget to zero `$a0` before each letter. PS: `blt $a0, 63, positionInHeap` does not seem to do anything useful.

Comment: ```morse:

 lb $t0, 0($a1)
 
 beq $t0, '\0', exit
 
 

decoderLoop:

 lb $t0, 0($a1)
 
 beq $t0, ' ', positionInHeap
 beq $t0, '\0', positionInHeap
 
 add $a0, $a0, $a0
 
 addi $a0, $a0, 1
 
 beq $t0, '.', isDot
 beq $t0, '-', isDash
 
 j exit
 
isDot:
 
 addi $a1, $a1, 1
 j decoderLoop

isDash:

 add $a0, $a0, 1
 addi $a1, $a1, 1
 j decoderLoop


positionInHeap:

 lb $t1, 0($a0)
 sb $t1, 0($a2)
 
 addi $a1, $a1, 1
 addi $a2, $a2, 1
 addi $v0, $v0, 1
 
 j morse

exit:
 
 jr $ra ```

Comment: Use the [edit] link to put new information into your question.

Comment: Do you mean by zero $a0, that i have to load the address of the decoder_heap back in $a0?

Comment: Ah, there indeed is the problem. You need to use an index for `k` and only add the address when you want to load the decoded letter.

Comment: So, could I just use a register like $t2 as an index and attempt the calculations on that?

Comment: I've revised it now, but it still doesn't work. It does work better than before but I still get the wrong answers. And I can't figure out why; it has to work at this point...

Comment: You also need to reset `$a0` to the beginning of the array. As is, it should work for the first letter.

Comment: Ok alright! Now it does work! Thank you so much for your help! I think I was just confused with the logic behind it. But now I understand it!

Comment: Consider posting a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you've resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
.data

test_msg: .asciiz ".... .- .-.. .-.. ---"

.text

morse: 

    lb $t0, 0($a1)
    
    beq $t0, '\0', exit 
    
    la $a0, decoder_heap 
    
    li $t2, 0 
    
    
decoderLoop:

    lb $t0, 0($a1)
    
    bge  $t2, 63, ignoreMorse
    
    
    beq $t0, ' ', positionInHeap
    beq $t0, '\0', positionInHeap
    
    add $t2, $t2, $t2
    
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    
    beq $t0, '.', isDot
    beq $t0, '-', isDash
    
    j exit
    
isDot:
    
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    j decoderLoop

isDash: 
    add $t2, $t2, 1
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    j decoderLoop


positionInHeap: 
    
    add $a0, $a0, $t2 # Die Adresse des ASCIIZ Zeichens wird ermittelt

    lb $t1, 0($a0)
    sb $t1, 0($a2)
    
    addi $a1, $a1, 1 
    addi $a2, $a2, 1 
    addi $v0, $v0, 1 
    
    j morse
    
ignoreMorse: 

    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    
    j morse

exit: 
    
    jr $ra
```

So, the main issue was that I couldn't figure out how to index the decoder heap correctly. It turned out that I had to store and calculate the index separately. I also reset the index and the pointer for the following morse-code.

Thank you again for your help Jester!